# jQuery push multiple td and keep them "pushed down"

Tags: jquery

I'm not using jQuery very often, but when I use it I'm having a hard time. I managed to write this with very basic skills, but I wanted to ask your help in this.

I want to do kinda checklist, and after You check your wanted "td" they keep checked, unless You push it again, to uncheck it.

So basically when You push td 1b it shows in picture 1, when you push td 2b it shows picture 2, but picture 1 disappears. I want it to make it like, You push 1 it shows picture 1, after You push 2 it shows picture 2 and 1. And so on, if You pushed these td for example: 1b, 2b, 3b and You don't want picture 2 to show anymore, You push td 2b again and now picture 2 disappears but pictures 1 and 3 keeps showing. And if possible pushed td changes color until you "unpush" it.

Also I added B-R td to switch colors of pictures, after You push it, colors switches and all td resets. So after it changes color its basically the same just other color.

It's hard for me to explain but in short: I wanna do checklist, each checked td shows a picture, if You uncheck one td only that picture disappears.

Could You help me with this? Thank You in advance!

My example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/mhz9n1yq/

jQuery code is a mess but it's best I could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".1bc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1b").show();
    $(".2b").hide();
    $(".3b").hide();
    $(".4b").hide();
    $(".5b").hide();
    $(".6b").hide();
    $(".topb").hide();
  });
  $(".2bc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1b").hide();
    $(".2b").show();
    $(".3b").hide();
    $(".4b").hide();
    $(".5b").hide();
    $(".6b").hide();
    $(".topb").hide();
  });
  $(".3bc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1b").hide();
    $(".2b").hide();
    $(".3b").show();
    $(".4b").hide();
    $(".5b").hide();
    $(".6b").hide();
    $(".topb").hide();
  });
  $(".4bc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1b").hide();
    $(".2b").hide();
    $(".3b").hide();
    $(".4b").show();
    $(".5b").hide();
    $(".6b").hide();
    $(".topb").hide();
  });
  $(".5bc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1b").hide();
    $(".2b").hide();
    $(".3b").hide();
    $(".4b").hide();
    $(".5b").show();
    $(".6b").hide();
    $(".topb").hide();
  });
  $(".6bc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1b").hide();
    $(".2b").hide();
    $(".3b").hide();
    $(".4b").hide();
    $(".5b").hide();
    $(".6b").show();
    $(".topb").hide();
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".1rc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1r").show();
    $(".2r").hide();
    $(".3r").hide();
    $(".4r").hide();
    $(".5r").hide();
    $(".6r").hide();
    $(".topr").hide();
  });
  $(".2rc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1r").hide();
    $(".2r").show();
    $(".3r").hide();
    $(".4r").hide();
    $(".5r").hide();
    $(".6r").hide();
    $(".topr").hide();
  });
  $(".3rc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1r").hide();
    $(".2r").hide();
    $(".3r").show();
    $(".4r").hide();
    $(".5r").hide();
    $(".6r").hide();
    $(".topr").hide();
  });
  $(".4rc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1r").hide();
    $(".2r").hide();
    $(".3r").hide();
    $(".4r").show();
    $(".5r").hide();
    $(".6r").hide();
    $(".topr").hide();
  });
  $(".5rc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1r").hide();
    $(".2r").hide();
    $(".3r").hide();
    $(".4r").hide();
    $(".5r").show();
    $(".6r").hide();
    $(".topr").hide();
  });
  $(".6rc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1r").hide();
    $(".2r").hide();
    $(".3r").hide();
    $(".4r").hide();
    $(".5r").hide();
    $(".6r").show();
    $(".topr").hide();
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".br").on('click', function() {
    $(".2").show();
    $(".1").hide();
    $(".black").hide();
    $(".red").show();
    $(".1b").hide();
    $(".2b").hide();
    $(".3b").hide();
    $(".4b").hide();
    $(".5b").hide();
    $(".6b").hide();
    $(".topb").hide();
    $(".topr").show();
  });
  $(".rb").on('click', function() {
    $(".2").hide();
    $(".1").show();
    $(".black").show();
    $(".red").hide();
    $(".1r").hide();
    $(".2r").hide();
    $(".3r").hide();
    $(".4r").hide();
    $(".5r").hide();
    $(".6r").hide();
    $(".topr").hide();
    $(".topb").show();
  });
});

$(".2").hide(); $(".topr").hide();

$(".1b").hide(); $(".2b").hide(); $(".3b").hide(); $(".4b").hide(); $(".5b").hide(); $(".6b").hide();

$(".1r").hide(); $(".2r").hide(); $(".3r").hide(); $(".4r").hide(); $(".5r").hide(); $(".6r").hide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), but seeing your code I have some tips regarding how to user jQuery more efficiently.

1. Use specific classes to select elements with similar behaviors.
2. Use `data` attributes to differ the specific behavior of each element

**Like so**:

In your code clicking on a `<td>` should trigger a `.toggle()` effect to one of the images, that behavior is shared between all the `<td>` you want, so instead of creating a `.click()` bind for each `<td>` element, you can alter your html to be:

```
<td class="js_toggle-image" data-show=".1b" style="text-align:center">1b</td>
<td class="js_toggle-image" data-show=".2b" style="text-align:center">2b</td>
<td class="js_toggle-image" data-show=".3b" style="text-align:center">3b</td>
<td class="js_toggle-image" data-show=".4b" style="text-align:center">4b</td>
<td class="js_toggle-image" data-show=".5b" style="text-align:center">5b</td>
<td class="js_toggle-image" data-show=".6b" style="text-align:center">6b</td>
```

That way once you fire `$('.js_toggle-image').click()` it will bind to all of them at once.

Also if you noticed I added `data-show=".1b"` to the td element, I will use that as the selector of the specific image I want to toggle, like so:

```
var toggleSelector;
$(".js_toggle-image").on('click', function() {
    toggleSelector = $(this).data('show');
    $(toggleSelector).toggle();
});
```

I've updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhz9n1yq/1/) with this and some other changes taking advantage of the multiple class selector.

Cheers!

**PS:** When I'm using a class with the purpose to get it via JavaScript I usually prefix it with `js_`, but that's not mandatory in any way, it just helps me to keep track of what is specific to **style** and to **behavior** .

Comment: Thanks for so fast reply, it helped me a lot! Exactly the way I wanted.

Comment: Maybe You could help me with one more thing, I wanted to make these selected td other color, so it would be obvious which one you clicked. After You click B-R these colors resets to way it was before. I kinda managed to do it, but if I click B-R few times, after I click any td color wont change now.

https://jsfiddle.net/mhz9n1yq/3/

I just added few lines in css and jquery.

Comment: @GintasB You nailed the toggle of the `bck` class, but upon clicking the B-R you've added a .css style, that's why it didn't work. What you want to do is remove the class you added doing `$('td').removeClass('bck')`, [like here](https://jsfiddle.net/mhz9n1yq/4/).

Comment: Thank You so much for this help and lessons, fast and on spot answers!:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use .toggle()

For example replace this:

```
$(".1bc").on('click', function() {
    $(".1b").show();
    $(".2b").hide();
    $(".3b").hide();
    $(".4b").hide();
    $(".5b").hide();
    $(".6b").hide();
    $(".topb").hide();
  });
```

with this:

```
  $(".1bc").on('click', function() {
  $( ".1b" ).toggle();
});
```

You can read more about [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

You can see the working example here:
http://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/EgKAGR

Comment: Thanks for help, helps a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the example below, just simply click the cells to toggle. And you can replace the `<span>` by your own images.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").children("div").toggle();
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).children("div").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 2px #000 solid;
  padding: 0;
}
td {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><span>1</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div><span>2</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div><span>3</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><span>4</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div><span>5</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div><span>6</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, a bit different than I wanted, but helped anyways:)